# R - does failed RegEx pattern matching originate in file conversion or use of tm package?

Tags: regex, r, tm

As a relative novice in R and programming, my first ever question in this forum is about regex pattern matching, specifically line breaks. First some background. I am trying to perform some preprocessing on a corpus of texts using R before processing them further on the NLP platform GATE. I convert the original pdf files to text as follows (the text files, unfortunately, go into the same folder):

```
dest <- "./MyFolderWithPDFfiles"
myfiles <- list.files(path = dest, pattern = "pdf", full.names = TRUE)
lapply(myfiles, function(i) system(paste('"C:/Program Files (x86)/xpdfbin-win-3.04/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE))
```

Then, having loaded the `tm` package and physically(!) moved the text files to another folder, I create a corpus:

```
TextFiles <- "./MyFolderWithTXTfiles"
EU <- Corpus(DirSource(TextFiles))
```

I then want to perform a series of custom transformations to clean the texts. I succeeded to replace a simple string as follows:

```
ReplaceText <- content_transformer(function(x, from, to) gsub(from, to, x, perl=T))
EU2 <- tm_map(EU, ReplaceText, "Table of contents", "TOC")
```

However, a pattern that is a 1-3 digit page number followed by two line breaks and a page break is causing me problems. I want to replace it with a blank space:

```
EU2 <- tm_map(EU, ReplaceText, "[0-9]{1,3}\n\n\f", " ")
```

The `([0-9]{1,3})` and `\f` alone match. The line breaks don't. If I copy text from one of the original .txt files into the RegExr online tool and test the expression `"[0-9]{1,3}\n\n\f"`, it matches. So the line breaks do exist in the original .txt file.

But when I view one of the .txt files as read into the EU corpus in R, there appear to be no line breaks even though the lines are obviously breaking before the margin, e.g.

```
[3] "PROGRESS TOWARDS ACCESSION"
[4] "1"
[5] ""
[6] "\fTable of contents"
```

Seeing this, I tried other patterns, e.g. to detect one or more blank space `("[0-9]{1,3}\s*\f")`, but no patterns worked.

So my questions are:

1. Am I converting and reading the files into R correctly? If so, what has happened to the line breaks?

   2. If no line breaks is normal, how can I pattern match the character on line 5? Is that not a blank
      space?
   3. (A tangential concern:) When converting the pdf files, is there code that will put them directly in a new folder?
   4. Apologies for extending this, but how can one print or inspect only a few lines of the text object? The `tm` commands and `head(EU)` print the entire object, each a very long text.

I know my problem(s) must appear simple and perhaps stupid, but one has to start somewhere and extensive searching has not revealed a source that explains comprehensively how to use RegExes to modify text objects in R. I am so frustrated and hope someone here will take pity and can help me.

Thanks for any advice you can offer.
Brigitte

p.s. I think it's not possible to upload attachments in this forum, therefore, here is a link to one of the original PDF documents: http://ec.europa.eu/enlargement/archives/pdf/key_documents/1998/czech_en.pdf
Because the doc is long, I created a snippet of the first 3 pages of the TXT doc, read it into the R corpus ('EU') and printed it to the console and this is it:

```
dput(EU[[2]])
structure(list(content = c("REGULAR REPORT", "FROM THE COMMISSION ON", 
"CZECH REPUBLIC'S", "PROGRESS TOWARDS ACCESSION ***********************", 
"1", "", "\fTable of contents", "A. Introduction", "a) Preface The Context of the Progress Report", 
"b) Relations between the European Union and the Czech Republic The enhanced Pre-Accession Strategy Recent developments in bilateral relations", 
"B. Criteria for membership", "1. Political criteria", "1.1. Democracy and the Rule of Law Parliament The Executive The judicial system Anti-Corruption measures", 
"1.2. Human Rights and the Protection of Minorities Civil and Political Rights Economic, Social and Cultural Rights Minority Rights and the Protection of Minorities", 
"1.3. General evaluation", "2. Economic criteria", "2.1. Introduction 2.2. Economic developments since the Commission published its Opinion", 
"Macroeconomic developments Structural reforms 2.3. Assessment in terms of the Copenhagen criteria The existence of a functioning market economy The capacity to cope with competitive pressure and market forces 2.4. General evaluation", 
"3. Ability to assume the obligations of Membership", "3.1. Internal Market without frontiers General framework The Four Freedoms Competition", 
"3.2. Innovation Information Society Education, Training and Youth Research and Technological Development Telecommunications Audio-visual", 
"3.3. Economic and Fiscal Affairs Economic and Monetary Union", 
"2", "", "\fTaxation Statistics "), meta = structure(list(author = character(0), 
    datetimestamp = structure(list(sec = 50.1142621040344, min = 33L, 
        hour = 15L, mday = 3L, mon = 10L, year = 114L, wday = 1L, 
        yday = 306L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
    "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), description = character(0), heading = character(0), 
    id = "CZ1998ProgressSnippet.txt", language = "en", origin = character(0)), .Names = c("author", 
"datetimestamp", "description", "heading", "id", "language", 
"origin"), class = "TextDocumentMeta")), .Names = c("content", 
"meta"), class = c("PlainTextDocument", "TextDocument"))
```

Comment: Can you print the character codes? It is the easiest way to debug.

Comment: Try the following pattern, `\\d{1,3}\\K\\R+` and see what happens.

Comment: or `\\d{1,3}\\K[\\r\\n\\f]+` and then replace the match with a blank space.

Comment: Unfortunately, both patterns suggested here don't match. That's why I wondered if my conversion of the pdf or reading the text docs into R is causing the problem. To nhahtdh, I'm afraid I don't know how to print the character codes (just googled, but to no avail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, working with text in R is not always a smooth experience! But you can get a lot done quickly with some effort (maybe too much effort!)

1. If you could share one of your PDF files or the output of `dput(EU)`, that might help to identify exactly how to capture your page numbers with regex. That would also add a reproducible example to your question, which is an important thing to have in questions here so that people can test their answers and make sure they work for your specific problem.
2. No need to put PDF and text files in separate folders, instead you can use a pattern like so:

   ```
   EU <- Corpus(DirSource(pattern = ".txt"))
   ```

This will only read the text files and ignore the PDF files

3. There is no 'snippet view' method in `tm`, which is annoying. I often use just `names(EU)` and `EU[[1]]` for quick looks

**UPDATE**

With the data you've just added, I'd suggest a slightly tangential approach. Do the regex work before passing the data to the `tm` package formats, like so:

```
# get the PDF
download.file("http://ec.europa.eu/enlargement/archives/pdf/key_documents/1998/czech_en.pdf", "my_pdf.pdf", method = "wget")

# get the file name of the PDF
myfiles <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "pdf", full.names = TRUE)

# convert to text (not my pdftotext is in a different location to you)
lapply(myfiles, function(i) system(paste('"C:/Program Files/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', paste0('"', i, '"')), wait = FALSE))

# read plain text int R
x1 <- readLines("my_pdf.txt")

# make into a single string
x2 <- paste(x1, collapse = " ")
# do some regex...
x3 <- gsub("Table of contents", "TOC", x2)
x4 <- gsub("[0-9]{1,3}  \f", "", x3)

# convert to corpus for text mining operations
x5 <- Corpus(VectorSource(x4))
```

With the snippet of data your provided using `dput`, the output from this method is

```
inspect(x5)
<<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
REGULAR REPORT FROM THE COMMISSION ON CZECH REPUBLIC'S PROGRESS TOWARDS ACCESSION *********************** TOC A. Introduction a) Preface The Context of the Progress Report b) Relations between the European Union and the Czech Republic The enhanced Pre-Accession Strategy Recent developments in bilateral relations B. Criteria for membership 1. Political criteria 1.1. Democracy and the Rule of Law Parliament The Executive The judicial system Anti-Corruption measures 1.2. Human Rights and the Protection of Minorities Civil and Political Rights Economic, Social and Cultural Rights Minority Rights and the Protection of Minorities 1.3. General evaluation 2. Economic criteria 2.1. Introduction 2.2. Economic developments since the Commission published its Opinion Macroeconomic developments Structural reforms 2.3. Assessment in terms of the Copenhagen criteria The existence of a functioning market economy The capacity to cope with competitive pressure and market forces 2.4. General evaluation 3. Ability to assume the obligations of Membership 3.1. Internal Market without frontiers General framework The Four Freedoms Competition 3.2. Innovation Information Society Education, Training and Youth Research and Technological Development Telecommunications Audio-visual 3.3. Economic and Fiscal Affairs Economic and Monetary Union Taxation Statistics
```

Comment: Thanks, Ben! I added a link to one of the PDFs and inserted sample output of `dput(EU[[2]]`. The code I use matches numbers, and the `\r` matches page breaks, but attempts to match the entire pattern don't work.

Comment: @Brigitte See how my updated answer works on your actual use case, let me know how you go.

Comment: Many thanks! I understand now that each line becomes a string element in the list object (so no line breaks or carriage returns are included in the R file) & R doesn't allow Regex matching over these strings. I used your solution & it works great. My problem is that my subsequent text analysis takes paragraphs into account. So I need to put carriage returns back after the regex operations. I can use, e.g., "££££" as the `collapse` argument of the `paste` command for later recognition. But do you know if R allows one to convert chosen characters to a carriage return?

Comment: Correction: I see it's not each line that becomes a string element in the list object, but a paragraph.

Comment: I just amazed myself by figuring it out:  `x5 <- strsplit(x4, split = "££££", fixed = TRUE)`

Comment: Sounds like you're making good progress. If your question is answered, consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to indicate to others that it solves your problem.